# Phrase to describe person who seeks 100% achievements in game

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

After completing a mission or beating a game, an achievement or trophy will pop up.  How do I describe such a person who sticks with it, to unlocking all the achievements of a game, no matter what time or effort is required?

I've considered **achievements maniac** or **achievements addictor**?

Other options?

**EDIT:** I mean to describe someone's personality. That kind of person maybe take too much time on beating challenges in game but never get bored - sort of perfectism and obsession. The word or phrase needs to be considered **derogatory**.

Comment: What's your context? Are you looking for the word simply to use it while speaking, or are you developing a game in which you'd like to name that achievement trophy?

Comment: @mikhailcazi I'm using the word in personal profile.

Comment: Do you wish to simply describe this quality about you, or do you want it to refer to your *game* achievements? Because, as @Susan says, someone who is **determined** or **driven** doesn't give up easily, but if you use those words it may not be clear that you are talking about completing achievements.

Comment: _Addictor_ sounds off anyway. Achievements **addict** is better and has a nice alliterative property as well.

Comment: I think _game addict_ would be just as appropriate as _achievement addict_.

Comment: Tone suiting the game and chiming well with the other trophy names would be better than being perfectly descriptive or even what would generally be valid English, due to headline style allowing for severe elision.

Comment: 'addictor' is not a word in English.

Comment: *achievement-obsessed [person]* could work, but I don't think there's any standard term for this.

Comment: A *Completionist* is how I always describe my friends who are like this, though it's not derogatory.  I've also used and heard *achievement whore*, which is certainly more derogatory.

Comment: I just call them OCD. Each achievement *generally* takes longer than the last, causing this exponential growth in play time before you finish them all. I'd rather move onto something else once I'm satisfied, or play something(competitive) PvP with essentially infinite replayability. Achievements mean next-to-nothing to me.

Comment: I'd go with the general term "perfectionist". For what it's worth, one game (World Of Goo) did jokingly refer to these as the "OCD scores", and nobody seems to have been offended by that. (And after having played through the game once, playing through again trying to meet/beat those scores did provide enough challenge to keep me interested for quite some time.)

Comment: @Doc: I've used Complelitist as a portmanteau of Completist and elitist to describe these people.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the context of video games or people who collect sets of things, the perfect word would be [**completionist**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/completionist) — if it weren't for the fact that you're looking for a word with derogatory connotations.

Derogatory phrases for things *related* to completionism — collecting things and interest in storytelling, for example — would be

- [**magpie**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/magpie?q=magpie): compulsive and not very discriminating collector of shiny things. "used figuratively to refer to a person who obsessively collects things or who chatters idly".
- [**trainspotter**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trainspotter): Someone who pays obsessive attention to details about trains, or by extension to any hobby which is not broadly accepted by society. "a person who obsessively studies the minutiae of any minority interest or specialized hobby".

Comment: +1 *Completionist* is the name of the final achievement awarded to completionist players in many games; *Assassins Creed III*, *StarCraft 2*, *Mass Effect*... The final achievement in the entirely achievement-based achievement-satire-game [Achievement Unlocked](http://armorgames.com/play/2893/achievement-unlocked) is called "Too Much Free Time". From my experience of gamer circles, "completionist" is usually not derogatory, even the opposite (various game guides describe *themselves* that way). "Too Much Free Time" is the derogatory, if verbose, alternative.

Comment: "Completionist" is also an adjective so "completionist [insult]" would fit the requirement of being derogatory.

Comment: Hmmm, _completionist_. I'll want to remember this word next Christmastime, when all those funny hats come round again.

Comment: @WangYudong: thanks for the accept, but I think that you should accept Tetrinity's answer instead. "Achievement whore" sounds to be exactly the term for what you asked for; even if you're going to avoid using it, it would appear to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 44):

In video-game circles, the unfortunate phrase **achievement whore** seems to be used rather often.

Precise usage varies. Occasionally the phrase will be used for somebody who simply tries very hard to gather all achievements in a given game. More frequently, however, it is used to denote somebody who buys and plays new games purely to gather more achievements, when they would not otherwise have considered playing said game.

Comment: Given the OP wants a more derogatory term, this was my immediate thought.

Comment: This is the proper "gamer" term especially since the op is looking for a derogatory term.

Comment: Yes, and note that the derogatory flavour doesn't preclude it from being used to refer to oneself at all. In fact "X whore" (X being a noun of some kind but *not* a proper noun) is often used to mean "do anything for X".

Answer (score 4):

I would consider this person **[driven](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/driven)** / achievement-driven: very **determined** to succeed; having a compulsive or urgent quality; propelled or motivated by something; used in combination **results-driven**.

likewise **determined**: having a strong feeling that you are going to do something and that you will not *let anyone or anything to stop you*.

consider **resolute**: marked by firm determination

All three connote some character quality of *stick-to-itiveness*, willpower, constancy, steadfastness, doing what you are supposed to do. They are not negative in the manner of *addicted*, *compulsive* or *obsessive*, which can also be used to describe determined gamers.

Edit: **[compulsive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compulsive)**: characterized by perfectionism, rigidity, and an obsessive concern with order and detail.

**[perfectionist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfectionist): one with propensity for being displeased with anything that is not perfect or does not meet extremely high standards.

Or **obsessive**: motivated by a persistent overriding idea or impulse, often associated with anxiety; continually preoccupied with a particular activity, person, or thing.

Comment: Thanks Susan. Please read my edited post. I'm looking for a word or phrase which is derogatory.

Comment: I'd have thought the *noun* usage (**an obsessive**) would fit OP's context perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previously mentioned "Achievement whore", another slightly less vulgar term (but still normally considered negative or derogatory) would be or **"Achievement Farmer"** (my personal choice for describing this phenomenon as a gamer), a term that relates to the practice of "Achievement Farming." **"Achievement Hunter"** is a term with even less negative connotations.

In gaming, farming generally refers to spending undue effort on a particular aspect of a game *other* than actually playing said game. For instance, WoW players may engage in "Gold Farming" to gain undue amounts of in-game cash. Typically, this involves lengthy repetition of various actions, much like a farmer methodically plowing or sowing his fields until the task is done.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bartle Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartle_Test) calls this type of gamer the '**Explorer**'. It's a person who tries to complete the game, looks in every nook and cranny, and be the first to do things that other people have not done yet. If there is rumored to be an Easter egg 5 hours walk away, they will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since *Completionist* is being bandied about and the desired term needs a derogatory edge, but not extreme like *Achievement Whore*, I would use *Compulsive Completionist*.

Answer (score 1):

The very first term that popped into my head was "[**anal retentive**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=anal%20retentive)".  It's not a gamer's term, but it describes the personality very well to my thinking, and it's almost always considered derogatory in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

These might match what you want:

single-minded

monomaniacal

Answer (score 0):

Consider **perseverative player**.  *[Perseverative](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/perseverative)* can mean

> 1.the tendency of an idea, impression, experience, etc. to persist or recur, or of an individual to continue a particular mental activity without the ability to shift easily to another at a change in stimulus
>
> 2.(psychiatry) the persistent and pathological repetition of a verbal or motor response, often seen in organic brain disease and schizophrenia

In the cited example, both may apply.

Comment: The request was for a derogatory phrase and it's considered inappropriate to use psychiatric terms as insults, these days.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that to consider the effort that a **completionist** puts forth in a derogatory manner, you would necessarily have to consider them an **overachiever** - somebody who achieves results beyond that which is expected / their natural talent levels.

Answer (score 0):

I think "addict" gives the right over-the-top, takes-it-too-far connotion. And "achievement" will never sound negative. So "Win Addict" or "win compulsive" might do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go a bit tongue in cheek, you could call them a **Pwner Achiever**.

Comment: I don't understand. Explain please?

Comment: @Skirmantas - It's a video game pun based on "Pwned" and "Over Achiever".

Answer (score -1):

In my WoW tenure, we've always called these players "ACP Whores" or "Achievement Whores."

Answer (score -1):

A phrase/word to describe a person who seeks 100% achievements in game could be "Winner".

Answer (score -1):

For the same impulse in arenas other than games, *perfectionist* works.